# $(-2)$-curves in complex $3$-folds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, birational-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ be a smooth complex $3$-fold, 
and let $C \subset X$ be an embedded smooth rational curve whose 
normal bundle $N_{C/X}$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{O}(-1) \oplus \mathscr{O}(-1)$. 
Is it true that a neighborhood of $C$ in $X$ is biholomorphic 
to some neighborhood of $C$ in $N_{C/X}$? Could you please give a reference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a theorem of Grauert for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this result appeared in "Uber Modifikationen und exzeptionelle analytische Mengen" (Mathematische Annalen, vol. 146, n.4) by H. Grauert. See the Corollary on p. 363, which also treats a much more general case.